# How to identify method order in disassembled C++ object

Tags: disassembly, c++

Here are some chunks:

```
  v13 = cocos2d::FileUtils::getInstance(v9);
  (*(void (__fastcall **)(char *))(*(_DWORD *)v13 + 64))(&v46);

  v19 = cocos2d::FileUtils::getInstance(fileHandle);
  v21 = *(void (__fastcall **)(char *, int, unsigned __int8 *))(*(_DWORD *)v19 + 28);
  v21(&v44, v20, &v42);

  v23 = cocos2d::FileUtils::getInstance(v22),
  v24 = (cocos2d::FileUtils *)(*(int (**)(void))(*(_DWORD *)v23 + 152))(),
```

cocos2d is an open source project, and I have downloaded it, but I have no idea how to determine what the order of the methods are.  So, how do I identify what method 28, 64, or 152 really is?  (Dead-listings only, can't execute the code to find the answer).

Comment: This looks more like a decompilation, but that's besides the point. Is this snippet from the library/dll itself or from a program written using the library?

Comment: The above is a Hex Rays "Pseudo-C" decompilation of some code from an .SO that has statically linked against the Cocos2D library.  I've picked up a little more information about it.  This is the method used to call virtual C++ methods.  But the question still remains.  How do I work out WHICH virtual C++ method these refer to.

Answer (score 1):

I presume the binary is fully optimized and stripped of debug info
My answer pertains to a windows binary (**ex getinst.exe**) but the generic concept applies to elf (**ex foo.so** )

some base presumptions about cocos2d from google are

1. appears to be 32 bit only
2. FileUtils appears to be a singleton implementation judging by the use of getInstance() and google

[FileUtils* s_sharedFileUtils

staticprotected

The singleton pointer of FileUtils.](https://cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.0alpha0/dc/d69/classcocos2d_1_1_file_utils.html#a290ffa656af77bffd9c938add78d2e06)

shown below is a bare minimum **proof of concept** singleton c++ code

```
:\>type getinst.cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Singleton
{
        static Singleton *instance;
        Singleton() {}
public:
        static Singleton *getInstance()
        {
                if (!instance)
                        instance = new Singleton;
                return instance;
        }
        virtual void funcone() { cout << "funcone\n"; }
        virtual void functwo() { cout << "functwo\n"; }
        virtual void functre() { cout << "functre\n"; }
        virtual void funcfor() { cout << "funcfor\n"; }
};
Singleton *Singleton::instance = nullptr;
int main()
{
        Singleton *s = s->getInstance();
        s->funcone();
        s->functwo();
        s->functre();
        s->funcfor();
        return 0;
}
```

compilation and linking with vs2017 as 32bit (x86) Full Optimization and nodebuginfo

```
:\>type complink.bat
cl /W4 /analyze:autolog- /EHsc /Ox /nologo getinst.cpp /link /release
```

contents of Directory pre and post compilation and execution of compiled binary

```
:\>ls -lg
total 5
-rw-r--r-- 1 197121  69 Aug 15 09:43 complink.bat
-rw-r--r-- 1 197121 603 Aug 15 09:24 getinst.cpp

:\>complink.bat

:\>cl /W4 /analyze:autolog- /EHsc /Ox /nologo getinst.cpp /link /release
getinst.cpp

:\>ls -lg
total 261
-rw-r--r-- 1 197121     69 Aug 15 09:43 complink.bat
-rw-r--r-- 1 197121    603 Aug 15 09:24 getinst.cpp
-rwxr-xr-x 1 197121 183808 Aug 15 09:49 getinst.exe
-rw-r--r-- 1 197121  76677 Aug 15 09:49 getinst.obj

:\>getinst.exe
funcone
functwo
functre
funcfor
```

lets dig into disassembly / find The RTTI / rename / etc

using a hex editor search for pattern "**.?A**"
I am using xxd a Commandline hex dumper

also I am providing a partial name **.?AVSing** to illustrate the point
but on an unknown binary  you maybe forced to analyze all the results of **.?A**

```
:\>xxd -g 4 getinst.exe |grep -B 1 -i ".?AVSing"
0002a8e0: 676f7279 40737464 40400000 8cf44100  gory@std@@....A.
0002a8f0: 00000000 2e3f4156 53696e67 6c65746f  .....?AVSingleto
```

the Address of Partial Mangled class name Starts at 0x2a8f8
( &StartofPattern + 4) == ( 0x2a8f4 + 4 ) == **Singleton@@**

```
:\>xxd -s 0x2a8f8 -l 16 getinst.exe
0002a8f8: 5369 6e67 6c65 746f 6e40 4000 8cf4 4100  Singleton@@...A.
```

Prepend ??_7 and Append 6B@ to this partial Mangled name
pass the conacatenated string to **undname.exe** or **c++filt** or [demangler.com](https://demangler.com) to get a Demangled or undecorated Name

```
:\>undname ??_7Singleton@@6B@
Microsoft (R) C++ Name Undecorator
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Undecoration of :- "??_7Singleton@@6B@"
is :- "const Singleton::`vftable'"
```

This Class name is part of a Structure Called _TypeDescriptor
https://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/msvc/language/predefined/

```
typedef struct _TypeDescriptor
{
    const void *pVFTable;
    void *spare;
    char name []; <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
} _TypeDescriptor;
```

which is a member of another structure

```
typedef const struct _s__RTTICompleteObjectLocator {
    unsigned long signature;
    unsigned long offset;
    unsigned long cdOffset;
    _TypeDescriptor *pTypeDescriptor; <<<<<<<<<<
    __RTTIClassHierarchyDescriptor *pClassDescriptor;
} __RTTICompleteObjectLocator;
```

find the cross references to these two structures
if the offset member is == 0 (SINGLE INHERITANCE)
the vtable follows the __RTTICompleteObjectLocator with methods

from the dump above

```
 _TypeDescriptor.name       = 0x2a8f4
 _TypeDescriptor.spare      = 0x2a8f0
  _TypeDescriptor.pVFTable  = (FO) 0x2a8ec -> 0x42baec (VA)
  FO = FileOffset ,VA = VirtualAddress
  VA == python -c "print(hex(0x2a8ec-0x29e00+0x42b000))"
```

find xref to 0x42baec There Are 2 xrefs

```
  :\>xxd -g4 getinst.exe | grep ecba4200
00027e90: 00000000 00000000 ecba4200 a08c4200  ..........B...B.
00027eb0: b88c4200 00000000 ecba4200 00000000  ..B.......B.....
```

From First Cross Reference

```
__RTTICompleteObjectLocator->pTypeDescriptor    = 0x27e98
__RTTICompleteObjectLocator.cdOffset            = 0x27e94
__RTTICompleteObjectLocator.offset              = 0x27e90
__RTTICompleteObjectLocator.signature           = 0x27e8c
```

find cross reference  to VA of 0x27e8c

```
dumpbin /SECTION:.rdata getinst.exe

SECTION HEADER #2
  .rdata name
    EA7E virtual size
   1C000 virtual address (0041C000 to 0042AA7D)
    EC00 size of raw data
   1B200 file pointer to raw data (0001B200 to 00029DFF)


python -c "print(hex(0x27e8c-0x1b200+0x41c000))"
0x428c8c

:\>xxd -g4 getinst.exe | grep 8c8c4200
0001b470: 66626974 20736574 00000000 8c8c4200  fbit set......B.
```

the methods follow 0x1b47c at 0x1b480

```
:\>xxd -g 4 -s 0x1b480 -l 64  getinst.exe
0001b480: 50204000 90204000 70204000 30204000  P @.. @.p @.0 @.
0001b490: 66756e63 6f6e650a 00000000 66756e63  funcone.....func
0001b4a0: 74776f0a 00000000 66756e63 7472650a  two.....functre.
0001b4b0: 00000000 66756e63 666f720a 00000000  ....funcfor.....
```

4 methods

```
0x402050 
0x402090
0x402070
0x402030
```

disasm of the methods

```
:\>dumpbin /disasm /range:0x402030,0x4020b0 getinst.exe

  00402030: 68 B4 C2 41 00     push        41C2B4h == 0x1b4b4 == funcfor
  00402035: 68 48 BE 42 00     push        42BE48h
  0040203A: E8 E1 F0 FF FF     call        00401120
  0040203F: 83 C4 08           add         esp,8
  00402042: C3                 ret
  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  00402050: 68 90 C2 41 00     push        41C290h  
  :\>python -c "print(hex(0x1b490-0x1b200+0x41c000))"
    0x41c290  
   :\>dumpbin /rawdata /range:0x41c290,0x41c29f getinst.exe
  0041C290: 66 75 6E 63 6F 6E 65 0A 00 00 00 00 66 75 6E 63  funcone.....func
  
  00402055: 68 48 BE 42 00     push        42BE48h
  0040205A: E8 C1 F0 FF FF     call        00401120
  0040205F: 83 C4 08           add         esp,8
  00402062: C3                 ret
  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  00402070: 68 A8 C2 41 00     push        41C2A8h == 0x1b4a8 == functre
  00402075: 68 48 BE 42 00     push        42BE48h
  0040207A: E8 A1 F0 FF FF     call        00401120
  0040207F: 83 C4 08           add         esp,8
  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  00402090: 68 9C C2 41 00     push        41C29Ch == 0x1b492 == functwo
  00402095: 68 48 BE 42 00     push        42BE48h
  0040209A: E8 81 F0 FF FF     call        00401120
  0040209F: 83 C4 08           add         esp,8
  004020A2: C3                 ret
  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

the 4 methods retrieved without symbol information using basic tools and manual fishing.

hope you can apply this to your cocos2d

Comment: This is BY FAR the most incredible answer I've ever seen here.  The amount of work required is STAGGERING!  The *ONLY* thing that makes it less than 100% ideal for my question is that my instance is in a Linux .SO compiled for ARM.  :-\

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IDA Pro, there are plugins to reconstruct the RTTI (runtime type identification) of the classes you are interested in. Take a look at [medigate](https://github.com/medigate-io/ida_medigate). There are other similar plugins as well which you can find on the web.